# Trying to get property 'product_id' of non-object

Tags: laravel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqDw9.png)I was using the laravel shopping cart when I got this error. Please ask how to fix[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LWlN.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFtCG.png)

Comment: if you are sure that product exists on the database then the problem lies on `$productId`, and yes you should always try to perform a null check before trying to access the property to see if the proper object was returned or null was returned by Query.

Comment: you have got to stop putting errors in images. copy paste the errors and put them as text. further, your images are not loading in the question. Please, edit the question. Or, delete it and post a new question with proper details.

Answer (score 1):

As per your code you are trying to access data directly without checking if data is return from the query:

You need to check first:

```
if ($product_info) {
 // do your code here
}
```

then redirect to your desire page

The product your are looking for is does not exist that's why you got that error.

Or else you can also use below query:

```
DB::table('tbl_product')->where('product_id', $productId)->firstOrFail();
```

> The findOrFail methods will retrieve the first result of the query; however, if no result is found, a Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException will be thrown:

Comment: @Minh Quân Glad to help, if this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted and do up votes, will be much appreciated !!

Comment: Hi. I tried to follow but still got the error Call to undefined method Illuminate \ Database \ Query \ Builder :: firstOrFail (). Hope the helping